# Passing a shared pointer to a function argument - what is the right way to assign it to a local variable

Tags: c++, c++11

```
//header file
void SetLogger(const std::shared_ptr<A>& log);

//cpp file
void SetLogger(const std::shared_ptr<A>& log)
{
    std::shared_ptr<A>&  mLog;
    mLog = log;
}
```

What is the best way to pass a shared_ptr as a function argument such that the owner ship of the object referred to does not to change / no increment of reference count and that no body should be able to delete it accept the owner?

So how should create a local shared_ptr in the function stating the restriction above?

```
Caller:

SetLogger(A.get()); // A is actually a shared pointer

Header:

void SetLogger(const A& log);

CPP File:

void SetLogger(const A& log)
{
    auto mLog = std::make_shared<A>(log);
}
```

Comment: @AlexeyAndronov Nobody is perfect. As long as you are able to get the question, consider not grammar, rather improve by editing.

Comment: @AlexeyAndronov: Please see https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct. Perhaps English is not the OP's first language. A far better course of action would be to edit the question.

Comment: Have a look at Herb Sutter's [GotW 91](https://herbsutter.com/2013/06/05/gotw-91-solution-smart-pointer-parameters/)...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The rule of thumb for smart pointer function arguments is: if there is no notion of ownership, don't pass the smart pointer, pass the pointee

1. as a reference, if it can't be null (preferable, see comments)
2. as a pointer, if it can be null (don't forget to check, though)

In case 1, any call to `delete` on the argument will fail to compile, which might be desirable. Further `const` qualification of the argument is orthogonal. In your example:

```
void SetLogger(const A& log);
```

called like this

```
auto a = std::make_shared<A>(/* ... */);

SetLogger(*a);
```

> So how should create a local shared_ptr in the function stating the restriction above?

If you need to copy the argument, there is indeed a notion of ownership. In that case, change your function signature to

```
void SetLogger(std::shared_ptr<A> log);
```

This will, however, increment the reference count, but if the object is managed by a `std::shared_ptr`, there is no sane solution to retain a copy without touching the reference count (for a good reason, this it what the class is about).

Comment: I tend to disagree with this rule. In a specific context, it can be clear than a naked pointer is a non-owning pointer. In real life, when there are new developers coming every few months, or when the code base is a bit old, this is far from obvious.

Comment: A compromise would be to define a non-owning smart pointer: syntaxic sugar around a naked pointer.

Comment: Thanks - but I have object A reference pointer only so how can I pass it as an object of type A?

Comment: I also prefer references over raw pointers being passed, which mitigates this issue.

Comment: Note: I'm really fine with the references.

Comment: @Programmer I'm sorry I don't get this, what do you mean by "I have object A reference pointer"?

Comment: I have update my question - I am doing the right way?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want the called function to have ownership over your object, there is nothing wrong in passing a raw pointer as stated [here](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#r3-a-raw-pointer-a-t-is-non-owning). Make your logger a `std::unique_ptr<A>` and pass the pointer using the `get()` method. In modern C++ it is now clear to all users of the function that they don't own that pointer and are not supposed to delete it. The owner will do that.